# Mode collapse vs local Optima in GANS

Tags: generative-adversarial-network

I confuse in what is the difference between mode collapse and local optima, I know what are those but I can't distinct them.

Mode Collapse:

Mode collapse occurs when a GAN generates a limited diversity of samples, typically focusing on a subset of modes (patterns or features) in the data distribution.
It leads to the generator producing similar or identical outputs, effectively ignoring parts of the target data distribution.
Mode collapse often results from the generator finding an easy-to-fool discriminator and converging to a state where it produces a few dominant samples.
Local Optima:

Local optima refer to situations where the GAN training process gets stuck in a suboptimal solution due to the non-convex nature of the GAN loss landscape.
In these cases, the GAN fails to find the ideal balance between the generator and discriminator, settling for a less optimal configuration.
Local optima can lead to the GAN generating lower-quality samples or **not fully capturing the complexity of the data distribution.**

I have got some problem with this definition "
...not fully capturing the complexity of the data distribution."

mode collapse also generate same output for multi input because it can't models the distribution of data.

**can anyone's to provide a new definition of difference between them?**

Thank you in advance for your help.